# std::list doesn't initialize correctly after it's content gets read from fstream

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, stdlist

**To explain briefly:** Using `<fstream>`, I write a `std::list` instance to a `.txt` file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

std::list<Item> list_1; //example list
list_1.push_back(Item(...));

std::ofstream file;
file.open("record.txt", std::ios::trunc);

if (file.is_open()) {
    file.write((char*)&list_1, sizeof(std::list<Item>)) << std::endl;

    file.close();
}
```

However, when I read from the same file and assign the data to a `std::list` instance:

```
file.open("record.txt", std::ios::in);
if (file.is_open()) {
    std::list<Item> list_1;
    file.read((char*)&list_1, sizeof(std::list<Item>));
}
```

It gives me an error when I try to access its elements. This is, however, not my problem. Because `std::list` stores the pointer to that element, I must store the elements manually, like I did here:

```
for (auto const& item : list_1) {
    file << item.amount << std::endl;
    file << item.value << std::endl;
    file << item.item_name << std::endl;
    file << (char*)&item.type << std::endl;
}
```

Then I read these values. Use the values to create a new `Item` instance and store it inside my `list`. Side note: I can access the `size()` property of the `list_1` from the `.txt` file because it is a member of `std::list<Item>` which lives on the stack. So it gets saved by the `ofstream`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_1.size(); i++) {
    int amount = 0;
    int value = 0;
    std::string item_name;
    Item_Type type = item;

    file >> amount;
    file >> value;
    file >> item_name;
    file >> (char*)&type;

    Item item(amount, value, item_name, type);
    main_player_inv.push_back(item);
```

I expect this to work, because now the `std::list` should have no uninitialized members, right?

Well, it gives me this error:

> this->_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead was 0x228B4050240

This basically means `list_1->_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead` is a pointer which points to memory out of bounds. The problem is, unlike the element pointers which I can manually save the values of and initialize, I can't access the data of `list_1->_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead` or edit it manually, as it is a private member. Or, there isn't a way I could find online.

So, I have two questions:

- Can I initialize `list_1->_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead` so that it points to a valid memory?
- Is there a way to more easily serialize a `std::list` and retrieve it's content?

If both of these questions are unanswerable, I would like to talk about what I'm trying to do:

The `std::list<Item>` is used as a character or an object's inventory. In my project, I want to store the items the `player` and objects such as containers have in a `std::list<Item>` instance. I thought this was the most fitting thing to do for an object-oriented Player structure. Here are some classes, for example:

**Player class**

```
class Player : public Object {
public:
    int level, experience;
    double health;
    float resistance; // 0.000 - 1.000
    std::list<Item> inventory;
public:
    Player() :
        level(0), experience(0), health(10.0), resistance(0.0f) {};
    Player(int x, int y, std::string obj_name, Obj_Type type, int level, int experience, double health, float resistence) :
        Object(x, y, obj_name, type), level(level), experience(experience), health(health), resistance(resistence) {};
};
```

**Item class**

```
struct Item {
public:
    unsigned int amount, value;
    std::string item_name;
    Item_Type type;  // enum
public:
    Item() :
        amount(0), value(0), item_name("undefined"), type(item) {};
    Item(int amount, int value, std::string item_name, Item_Type type) :
        amount(amount), value(value), item_name(item_name), type(type) {};
};
```

If you know a better way to store player items, items being class instances; or know altogether a better way to do this, please help me.

Comment: None of the classes you used are trivial types, so `file.write((char*)&list_1, sizeof(std::list<Item>))` and `file.read((char*)&list_1, sizeof(std::list<Item>));` are both completely wrong. You need to write some actual serialization and deserialization code, you can't just dump the bytes into a file

Comment: Similarly `file << (char*)&item.type` is also wrong, because it's not a null-terminated string

Comment: `std::list<Item>` is just the list head. The `Item`s are all stored separately on the heap, and also not included in `sizeof(std::list<Item>)`.

Comment: tldr; anytime you use a c-style cast, reinterpret_cast, or const_cast, it's almost always a bug.

Comment: `list` is a linked list, a chain of items connected together by pointers. When you `write` a pointer, the address, not the data at the address, is written into the stream. As you can expect, the address of the data is kind of useless. The data may not be at the same place, or exist at all, when the file is read back. And if the data is still there, it's not safe to have two linked lists both thinking they own the pointed-at item and can do whatever they want with it.

Comment: @user4581301 yes i know that. That's why I've manually written the list's content down. But i can't write down the value of   list_1->_Mypair._Myval2._Myhead   which is my problem

Comment: @GaenoxL that is because you are focusing on the wrong thing. That is an internal field, pretend it doesn't exist. Focus only on your own classes, reading/writing the fields of your class instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read/write the raw bytes of a `std::list` object (or any other non-trivial type), as you would be writing/reading raw pointers and other internal data members that you don't need to concern yourself with.

You must (de)serialize your class's individual data members instead, as you have already discovered.

I would suggest a binary format instead of a textual format, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar<T>::value, bool> = true>
void writeToStream(std::ostream &out, const T &value) {
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar<T>::value, bool> = true>
void readFromStream(std::istream &in, T &value) {
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}

void writeToStream(std::ostream &out, const std::string &value) {
    size_t size = value.size();
    writeToStream(out, size);
    out.write(value.c_str(), size);
}

void readFromStream(std::istream &in, std::string &value) {
    size_t size;
    readFromStream(in, size);
    value.resize(size);
    in.read(value.data() /* or: &value[0] */, size);
}

template <typename Container>
void writeToStream(std::ostream &out, const Container &items) {
    size_t count = items.size();
    writeToStream(out, count);
    for(const auto& item : items) {
        writeToStream(out, item);
    }
}

template <typename Container>
void readFromStream(std::istream &in, Container &items) {
    size_t count;
    readFromStream(in, count);
    items.reserve(count);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        Container::value_type item;
        readFromStream(in, item);
        items.push_back(item);
    }
}

template<typename Container>
void writeToFile(const std::string &fileName, const Container &items) {
    std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    file.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit);
    writeToStream(file, items);
}

template<typename Container>
void readFromFile(const std::string &fileName, Container &items) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    readFromStream(file, items);
}
```

```
struct Item {
public:
    unsigned int amount, value;
    std::string item_name;
    Item_Type type;  // enum
public:
    Item() :
        amount(0), value(0), item_name("undefined"), type(item) {};
    Item(int amount, int value, std::string item_name, Item_Type type) :
        amount(amount), value(value), item_name(item_name), type(type) {};

    void writeTo(std::ostream &out) const {
        writeToStream(out, amount);
        writeToStream(out, value);
        writeToStream(out, item_name);
        writeToStream(out, type);
    }

    void readFrom(std::istream &in) {
        readFromStream(in, amount);
        readFromStream(in, value);
        readFromStream(in, item_name);
        readFromStream(in, type);
    }
};

void writeToStream(std::ostream &out, const Item &item) {
    item.writeTo(out);
}

void readFromStream(std::istream &in, Item &item) {
    item.readFrom(in);
}
```

```
class Player : public Object {
public:
    int level, experience;
    double health;
    float resistance; // 0.000 - 1.000
    std::list<Item> inventory;
public:
    Player() :
        level(0), experience(0), health(10.0), resistance(0.0f) {};
    Player(int x, int y, std::string obj_name, Obj_Type type, int level, int experience, double health, float resistence) :
        Object(x, y, obj_name, type), level(level), experience(experience), health(health), resistance(resistence) {};

    void writeTo(std::ostream &out) const {
        writeToStream(out, level);
        writeToStream(out, experience);
        writeToStream(out, health);
        writeToStream(out, resistance);
        writeToStream(out, inventory);
    }

    void readFrom(std::istream &in) {
        readFromStream(in, level);
        readFromStream(in, experience);
        readFromStream(in, health);
        readFromStream(in, resistance);
        readFromStream(in, inventory);
    }
};

void writeToStream(std::ostream &out, const Player &player) {
    player.writeTo(out);
}

void readFromStream(std::istream &in, Player &player) {
    player.readFrom(in);
}
```

```
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<Item> list_1; //example list
    list_1.push_back(Item(...));

    writeToFile("record.txt", list_1);

    list_1.clear();

    readFromFile("record.txt", list_1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want a textual file, then use `operator<<` and `operator>>` instead, overriding them in your classes, eg:

(feel free to tweak this to use whatever formatting you want...)

```
#include <limits>

void discardLine(std::istream &in) {
    in.ignore(std::numeeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

template<typename CharT, typename Traits>
void streamFailed(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits> &stream) {
    stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}

template <typename Container>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Container &items) {
    out << '[' << items.size() << '\n';
    for(const auto& item : items) {
        out << item << '\n';
    }
    out << ']\n';
    return out;
}

template <typename Container>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Container &items) {
    char ch;
    in >> ch;
    if (ch != '[') {
        streamFailed(in);
    } else {
        size_t count;
        in >> count;
        discardLine(in);
        items.reserve(count);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            Container::value_type item;
            in >> item;
            items.push_back(item);
        }
        in >> ch;
        if (ch != '[') {
            streamFailed(in);
        }
    }
}

template<typename Container>
void writeToFile(const std::string &fileName, const Container &items) {
    std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    file.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit);
    file << items;
}

template<typename Container>
void readFromFile(const std::string &fileName, Container &items) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
    file >> items;
}
```

```
struct Item {
public:
    unsigned int amount, value;
    std::string item_name;
    Item_Type type;  // enum
public:
    Item() :
        amount(0), value(0), item_name("undefined"), type(item) {};
    Item(int amount, int value, std::string item_name, Item_Type type) :
        amount(amount), value(value), item_name(item_name), type(type) {};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Item &item) {
        out << '(' << item.amount << ' ' << item.value << ' ' << static_cast<int>(item.type) << ' ' << item.item_name << ')';
        return out;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Item &item) {
        char ch;
        in >> ch;
        if (ch != '(') {
            streamFailed(in);
        } else {
            int itype;
            in >> item.amount >> item.value >> itype;
            item.type = static_cast<Item_Type>(itype);
            std::getline(in >> std::ws, item_name, ')');
        }
        return in;
    }
};
```

```
class Player : public Object {
public:
    int level, experience;
    double health;
    float resistance; // 0.000 - 1.000
    std::list<Item> inventory;
public:
    Player() :
        level(0), experience(0), health(10.0), resistance(0.0f) {};
    Player(int x, int y, std::string obj_name, Obj_Type type, int level, int experience, double health, float resistence) :
        Object(x, y, obj_name, type), level(level), experience(experience), health(health), resistance(resistence) {};

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Player &player) {
        out << '(' << level << ' ' << experience << ' ' health << ' ' << resistance << '\n';
        out << inventory;
        out << ')';
        return out;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Player &player) {
        char ch;
        in >> ch;
        if (ch != '(') {
            streamFailed(in);
        } else {
            in >> player.level >> player.experience >> player.health >> player.resistance >> player.inventory;
            in >> ch;
            if (ch != ')') {
                streamFailed(in);
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
};
```

```
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<Item> list_1; //example list
    list_1.push_back(Item(...));

    writeToFile("record.txt", list_1);

    list_1.clear();

    readFromFile("record.txt", list_1);
    
    return 0;
}
```